# when bucket files get created in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

In Bucketing at what stage in hive do bucket files get created?

```
create table emp( id int, name string, country string)
 clustered by( country)
INTO 2 BUCKETS
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile ;
```

if I have 20 buckets and only 4 rows how many files will get created?

Answer (score 0):

Buckets are created when you create your table. They will be located in your Hive warehouse as standalone files within your table catalog. Once you insert new record in your bucket table Hive will compute the hash of the value of bucket column and will get the pointer of the bucket file. For your 20 buckets you will have 20 empty files on the start, but the exact place of your 4 records would depend on the result of hash function upon the bucket column value:

```
**record.country.value => hashfunction(record.country.value) = bucketNumber**
```

You can reproduce it by following the steps described in Bucket table section in this [article](https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/02/16/structuring-hadoop-data-through-hive-and-sql/)